# Error:Assertion Failed: Could not find "example.login" template or view in Ember.js

Tags: javascript, html, ember.js, visual-studio-2013

I am using Ember.js on Visual Studio 2013.
I have create a page named "index.hmtl" where there is this code:

```
<body>
  <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="application">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="row-fluid">
        <div class="span2">
          <div class="well sidebar-nav">
            <ul class="nav nav-list">
              <li class="nav-header">Hello</li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="span10">
          {{outlet}}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <footer class="footer">
      <div class="container">
        <p>&nbsp;</p>
      </div>
    </footer>
  </script>
  <!-- App -->
  <script src="Scripts/libs/jquery-2.1.1.js"></script>
  <script src="Scripts/libs/handlebars-v2.0.0.js"></script>
  <script src="Scripts/libs/ember-template-compiler-1.10.0.js"></script>
  <script src="Scripts/libs/ember.js"></script>
  <script src="Scripts/libs/ember-data.js"></script>
  <script src="Scripts/app/application.js"></script>
</body>
```

And in my application.js there is this code:

```
window.Example = Ember.Application.create();

Example.Router.map(function () {
    this.resource('example', { path: '/' }, function () {
        this.route('login');
        this.route('articles');
        this.resource('example.articlemode', { path: '/articlemode' }, function () {
            this.resource('articlemode', { path: '/:articlemode_id' });
        });
    });


});

Example.ExampleRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    setupController: function (controller, model) {
        var host = this.store.adapterFor('Example').get('host');
        var namespace = this.store.adapterFor('Example').get('namespace');
        controller.set('host', host);
        controller.set('namespace', namespace);
        controller.set('baseUrl', host + namespace);
    },

    renderTemplate: function() {
        this.render('example.login');
    }

}); 
Example.LoginRoute = Ember.Route.extend({    
    setupController: function (controller, model) {
        controller.reset();
    }
});


Example.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    setupController: function (controller) {
        controller.set('example', 'Hello');
    }
});

//Models
Example.Login = DS.Model.extend({
    username: DS.attr('string'),
    password: DS.attr('string')
});
```

There is an `Example.ExampleLoginController` too...

In my Project there is a directory named `Templates` where there is a `login.html` file but If I run my application, I have this error:

`"Error:Assertion Failed: Could not find "example.login" template or view in Ember.js"`

I have trie to change `this.render('example.login');` with `this.render('
login');` or `example/login` but the error remains I really don't understand why

Answer (score 3):

You will need to precompile your templates into JavaScript, Ember will not automatically load templates for you and compile them. I'd highly recommend you use [Ember CLI](http://www.ember-cli.com/), it provides a strong conventional project structure and will do all the template compilation for you + some other useful things.

If using Ember CLI isn't an option for you because your code is tightly coupled to your backend code (i.e. an old website that does most of the rendering on the server) you can always procompile your templates using [Gulp](https://github.com/swelham/gulp-ember-templates), [Grunt](https://github.com/dgeb/grunt-ember-templates) or some other build tool.

Comment: You are right... but I have to use it in Visual studio

Comment: @LizLamperouge I don't see how these are necessarily mutually exclusive. What would prevent you from using Ember CLI when using Visual Studio?

Comment: I don't want to install package manually, but include them with <script src>. I have to do this for work

Comment: @LizLamperouge Ember CLI also includes dependencies in a normal script tag, it just adds an extra build step you're going to have to do anyways to compile your templates. Visual Studio is just an IDE, you should be able to edit the files in Ember CLI projects without any issues.

If you say "I have to do this for work" I can only conclude someone is forcing you to use this solution, in which case I would strongly recommend you discuss this with said person.